# XML file downloaded from URL <b> / </b> not recognised

Tags: java, xml, xpath, google-directions-api

I have used this [Java NIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java) to download a xml file from Google Direction.

A [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4251080/Capture.PNG) of the xml file opened in IE. This is another [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4251080/Capture1.PNG) of how it should look right.

For some reason the   tags doesn't seem to be recognized, so when I use xPath to evaulate and query the XML file, I get the output like below:

```
Continue onto <b>Derwent St</b>

 338
 0.3 km

At the roundabout, take the <b>1st</b> exit onto <b>Corporation St</b>

 102
 0.1 km
```

is there a simpler way to fix this or do I have to use SAX parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<b>` appears as *data* not a tag. It will either be represented as `&lt;b&gt;` or appear in a CDATA block.

i.e. the XML contains a fragment of HTML as data. It doesn't include namespaced XHTML.

The output is what you should expect.

What do you next depends on what you want to achieve. Whatever it is, you need to get the data as a string (rather then a textNode) and treat that string as HTML, not text.

If you want to query the HTML, then you need to run it through an HTML parser first.